# AS3 for ios : how to serialize an array and then save it

Tags: ios, json, actionscript-3

I have an multidimentional array and I want to serialize it and then save it using SharedObjects.
I tried many things, but each time there is a problem.

JSON : can't have types with it.

ByteArray : the result is not a String, then the SharedObject doesn't want to save it.

May be SharedObjects are not part of the solution.

So my question : is there a simple solution to save an array on disc and to retrieve this array ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the array contain?

Comment: You can save objects in SharedObjects, you just need to register the class first.  `flash.net.registerClassAlias`

Comment: @Baris : it contains only Strings and Numbers

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices : you mean I don't need to serialize it before ?

Comment: If it is just Strings and numbers just json encoding and storing in shared object should work.

Comment: @BarışUşaklı : It's true, but SO are able to store directly arrays, without serialization, which is easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `flash.net.registerClassAlias`.

So if I had a class like this:

```
package com {
    public class Bob {
        public var myArray:Array;
    }
}
```

I could do this:

```
registerClassAlias("com.Bob", Bob);
```

Then you can save Bob class objects into your shared objects (or rather retrieve them again)

Full example:

```
//register the class - you only need to do this once in your class
registerClassAlias("com.Bob", Bob);
```

---

```
//Lets save a Bob instance into a shared object
var bob:Bob = new Bob();
bob.myArray = ["blah","blah","blah"];

var bobSO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Bob");          
bobSO.data.bob = new Bob();
bobSO.flush();
```

---

```
//now at a later time, let's retrieve it
var bobInstance:Bob;
var bobSO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Bob");
if (bobSO.size > 0 && bobSO.data.bob && bobSO.data.bob != undefined) {
    bobInstance = bobSO.data.bob;
}
```

Keep in mind, that you'll need to register ALL classes that are used (if you have different classes stored in your array).

Comment: Thank you. I gone test this. So If I understand, I don't need to serialize an array to stock it in SO, but I need to register it's class before, right ? An array isn't already registered ?

Comment: It works on array without registering class, as Array seem to be already registered.
I test this : 
    import flash.net.SharedObject;

    var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("testApp");
    var test:Number = Math.random();

    var a:Array = new Array("test", "pascal", 1, test);
    trace(a);
    if (so.size > 0 && so.data.bob && so.data.bob != undefined) {
 trace("loaded : "+so.data.bob);
    }
    so.data.bob = a;
    so.flush();

and the job is done.
Thank you anyway, as you make me solve the problem.

Comment: You don't have to register primative classes,  e.g those you can use in AS3 without an import  (Stirng/Number/Int/Array etc)