# Red5 throws "Error loading class" when using a custom class as a SharedObject

Tags: actionscript-3, red5, amf, shared-objects

From an AS3 Flash app, I'm trying to set a SharedObject to an instance of a custom class I've created. From what I can tell, as soon as I call `sharedObject.setProperty("propertyName", myCustomClass)` Red5 throws "Error loading class" and then disconnects the client because decoding failed.

It seems that plenty of other people have had similar problems, but everything I've found is about creating SharedObjects on the server-side. I'm having trouble finding much about creating the SharedObject on the client-side (in the Flash app). I'm just using the included "live" Red5 app out of the box.

Here's the actual error I see in the Red5 logs...

```
[ERROR] [NioProcessor-7] org.red5.io.amf.Input - Error loading class: com.striparcade.API.Player
[ERROR] [NioProcessor-7] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Error decoding buffer
```

`com.striparcade.API.Player` is the custom class in question. This class implements IExternalizable, includes writeExternal() and readExternal() methods, and a call to registerClassAlias(). It seems to serialize just fine.

Surely I don't have to recreate this class in the Red5 app as well? Shouldn't Red5 just take the data and pass it along to the other clients when needed? Any idea what I'm missing?

Using Red5 1.0.1, btw. I see that a lot of bugs regarding AMF3 encoding were fixed around version .7. Also, just testing locally on a Windows 7 machine right now.

Comment: See my answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667848/as3-for-ios-how-to-serialize-an-array-and-then-save-it/15668079#15668079

Comment: I'm already calling `registerClassAlias`.

Comment: you need to register EVERY class that may be referenced inside you `Player` class (and any classes within those classes),  are you sure you're doing that?  I have no experience with Red5 so if the issue lies there someone else will have to comment

Comment: Yeah, I've boiled it down to just a simple CustomClass with a single String property for testing purposes, and get the same problem. The issue appears to be with Red5, or at least with the included "live" Red5 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, but I'm no Red5 expert so take the following explanation with a grain of salt and correct me if I'm wrong... It seems that either Red5, or the "live" application included with Red5, attempts to instantiate whatever objects it receives via a SharedObject on the server-side. So, I believe you would actually need to replicate in Java whatever CustomClasses you're sharing from the client-side in AS3. Seems really odd to me, but that's all I can gather, and that would explain the Red5 error logs.

This was unacceptable for my needs, as I plan to have other programmers take my client-side code as an API and abstract away the server-side details... so recreating whatever classes they come up with on the server isn't really feasible.

An easy workaround is to "wrap" whatever you're sharing in a ByteArray and then unwrap it when you retrieve it. Red5 doesn't seem to complain about ByteArrays, and happily broadcasts them out to the client with no knowledge of what's inside. Here are a couple functions I whipped up to handle this...

```
    private function setRed5Property(propertyName:String, data:Object):void
    {
        var dataBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        dataBytes.writeObject(data);

        _red5SharedObject.setProperty(propertyName, dataBytes);
        _red5SharedObject.setDirty(propertyName);
    }

    private function getRed5Property(propertyName:String):Object
    {
        var dataBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        dataBytes.writeBytes(_red5SharedObject.data[propertyName]);
        dataBytes.position = 0;

        return dataBytes.readObject() as Object;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `registerClassAlias("com.striparcade.API.Player",com.striparcade.API.Player)` before you do anything with SharedObject and this class. If it's OK, make sure you are able to call `getDefinitionByName("com.striparcade.API.Player")` and receive a non-null value right prior to reading a SO. It's possible that the class definition is either not compiled into the SWF, or it's included on later frames than where you read the SO.

Comment: I've moved `registerClassAlias("com.striparcade.API.Player",com.striparcade.API.Player)` to the first line of the constructor in my main class. `getDefinitionByName("com.striparcade.API.Player")` returns `[class Player]` right before a call to `setProperty` containing an instance of Player. It all looks correct, but but still the same error in the Red5 logs.